# How to find a document from mongodb using mongoose based on query and then insert some data to it and save back?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have my Model as

```
var Model = {"name":String,"email":String,"notes":[{"time":Date,"title":String,"description":String}]
```

And I want to find document based on the email, and then add a note to the array. And then save it back.
What I tried is,

```
var updatedNote = {};     
Model.findOne({'email':'test@test.com'},function(err, note){
    for(var property in note._doc){
        if(note._doc.hasOwnProperty(property)){
            updatedNote[property] = note._doc[property];
        };
    }
    updatedNote.notes.push(newNote);
    note._doc = updatedNote;
    note.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/notes');
        }
    })
});
```

But it is throwing error as "Object does not have save method". I don't want to use findByIdAndUpdate() as i am leaving this responsibility of generating id on mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what most of that code is doing.  If I wanted to add a note to the document (I'm assuming newNote is defined elsewhere), I'd just do:

```
Model.findOne({'email':'test@test.com'},function(err, note){

     note.notes.push(newNote);
     note.save(function(err){});
});
```

Comment: Thanks you just saved my one more day. I tried lot of things like first find by query then try fetching the notes array , update it and save but none was working. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get all those other crazy ideas?